# Error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'relProductsPrices' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I'm upgrading and optimizing an old table structure.
In order to properly work with `replace into`, I'm removing old zombie entries that interfer with the new unique key over 2 columns.

**Query:**

```
 DELETE from `relProductsPrices` where `ID` in 

  (SELECT scanA.ID from `relProductsPrices` as scanA 
             inner join `relProductsPrices` as scanB 

   where scanA.ID        < scanB.ID 
     and scanA.product   = scanB.product
     and scanA.priceName = scanB.priceName);
```

**Error:**

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'relProductsPrices' for update in FROM clause
```

I'm not sure how to get this into one mySQL Query properly, at this time?

I hope this question is no duplicate entry, I seemed unable to find a similar, adaptable entry. There are questions regarding this error, but I'm not having an update query here at all, and the solution most people state (create a subselect) was already done by me beforehand already.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution most people state is to have another level of subselect. You only have one level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM `relProductsPrices` 
WHERE `ID` IN ( 
     SELECT 
       tmp.ID 
     FROM (
       SELECT 
         scanA.ID 
       FROM 
         `relProductsPrices` as scanA 
       INNER JOIN `relProductsPrices` as scanB 
         ON scanA.ID        < scanB.ID 
         AND scanA.product   = scanB.product
         AND scanA.priceName = scanB.priceName
     ) as tmp
 );
```

Comment: The logic behind this really confuses me, but honestly, it works like a charm. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Np, glad it worked :) As @MartinSmith well pointed out you needed another level of subselect

Comment: Yea I somehow missed that. But honestly... I really don't get how this is more logical than what I've tried, eventhough it works. Thanks